# Q: Solving the following recurrence: T(n) = 8T(n/8) + n log n

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the following recurrence:

```
T(n) = 8T(n/8) + n* log n.
```

I currently have done the following but am not sure if I am on the right track:

```
1. T(n)= 8 T(n/8) + n log n;
2. T(n)= 8^2 T(n/8^2) + n log (n/8) + n log n
3. T(n)= 8^3 T(n/8^3) + n log (n/8^2) + n log (n/8) + n log n
```

So the general formula came up for me as:

```
T(n)= 8^k T(n/8^k) + n log(n* n/8 * n/8^2 * ... * n/8^k).
```

And i am not sure how to continue this. I tried to rewrite the `log` as
`n^k / 8^(k*(k+1)/2)`, but I still don't see the solution.

Comment: I think this questions belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Almost there, but you have an off-by-one error, which you can see by setting `k = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Set `k = log_8(n)` then you can solve for `T(n)`

Comment: Would be helpful to explain *why* this is the correct value to substitute.

Comment: Because you've now worked out for the formula for arbitrary k, you can now assume a base case and solve for arbitrary n.

Answer (score 0):

Let `n = 2^m`. We rewrite the recurrence as

```
T(2^m) = 8.T(2^(m-1)) + n.m log(8).
```

Now, with `T(2^m) = n.S(m)`,

```
n.S(m) = 8.n/8.S(m-1) + n.m log(8)
```

which simplifies to

```
S(m) = S(m-1) + m.log(8),
```

leading to the triangular numbers.